# on error is it possible to ignore exception?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

how do i ignore exceptions in c#?

i am reading a remote xml file, and sometimes the tag doesnt exist and it throws an exception. how do i ignore the exception and goto next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
 yourXmlDocument.LoadXML("xml is here");
}catch{
 //It has failed.
}
```

You could be even more specific and only catch errors from LoadXML

```
try
{
    yourXmlDocument.LoadXML("xml is here");
}catch(System.Xml.XmlException e){
    //It has failed.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> how do i ignore exceptions in c#?

## Don't.

Exceptions are trying to tell you that **something is wrong with your code.**

If you're getting an exception during XML parsing because a specific element doesn't exist, then rewrite the code to *check whether or not that element exists* before trying to read it.

---

If you are asking how to *handle* a specific exception, then you can wrap it in a try-catch block:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    doc.Load(url);
}
catch (XmlException)
{
    // Handle the error here
    return (default value);
}
// Start going through the XmlDocument
```

The above code would handle the specific case where the XML is *malformed*.  However, if the XML is well-formed but your code is throwing an exception because a particular *element* does not exist and you assumed that it would, then don't use exception-handling code at all; simply check that it exists before trying to read it.

Comment: Checking a huge xml document can sometimes be living hell >_< You have attributes, things that look like xml code but are really actually text in an XML attribute <message content="<sarcasm>i like zac effron</sarcasm>" />, closing tags <xml></xml>, auto-closing tags or w/e they're called <person id="asdf" /> etc...  Looking for errors and finding them by yourself is something you'd want to do.  However, the complexity you'll be experiencing [along with all the iffy cases] is probably worse than the small overhead you'll get from using a try/catch.  Of course, thats just my opinion...

Comment: @ItzWarty: If the XML is malformed, that's true. But the question seems to strongly implied that the XML has already been loaded into a DOM or `XmlReader` and that the code is simply assuming an element to exist that is not there.

Comment: Do you have a schema for the XML defined?  If so, why not validate against that to start with.  Limits the exceptions and the need to handle individual element issues.

Comment: Aaron beat me to it, looks like.

Comment: @Steve: Excellent point about the schema, although I suspect that there is probably no schema, otherwise the XML wouldn't really need to be directly parsed/walked at all (it could be deserialized into a strong-typed object).

Answer (score 1):

**Never ever ignore exceptions.** These "I am sure I can safely ignore this" sometimes cause the worst and hardest to find bugs.

Always **at least log the exception**. Optionally, also use `Debug.Fail` method, which will display a dialog with exception details in your debug build - this will help you to diagnose most problems much better.

In this particular case (XML parsing), there surely is a way how to handle cases when the data is not found gracefully, without catching and ignoring exceptions - feel free to edit the answer to show us what exact xml parsing method you are using and we can tell you how to avoid the exceptions in the first place.

Since you may be asking about a generic case, this is how you deal with exceptions if you want to "ignore" them (if you do not wish to display them to the user):

```
try
{
  //do something that throws an exception
}
catch(Exception ex) //or even better: catch a specific exception type
{
  //do not ignore the exception, at least log it
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail(ex.Message, ex.ToString());
  log.Debug("Probably expected error happened: " + ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to answer you question, if you put your code in a Try Catch block and then for the exception in question, simply catch it and do nothing.

That being said, why not just check for a null tag while processing rather than rely on exception handling?  Exception handling has more overhead generally than checking for a condition and if there is an expected case where something may not exist, you should handle that case in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a try/catch around the code and do nothing with the exception that is generated.

Answer (score 0):

If the **exception is remote**, like you say, and you're only getting the string version of its message or result, then you won't be able to use exception handling mechanisms on it. However you might be able to cobble something together where you recognize the strings and do something.

If you get the Exception object then you can [pull out the good old **try/catch** stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(VS.80).aspx) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-catch block. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28VS.80%29.aspx